# how to import values to styled components from another file

Tags: javascript, reactjs, import, styled-components, background-color

Im trying to pass a value imported from another file to my styled component , but i get notification from my editor that the syntax is wrong , whats the correct way of writing this or how i can pass the value for the background color to this component?

```
import { Colors } from "../theme/Theme";

const FootergEl = styled.div`
  position: relative;
  height: 482px;
  width: 100vw;
  margin-top: 196px;
  background-color: `${Colors.Brand.BGFooter}`;
`;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the correct way do this is as below

```
import { Colors } from "../theme/Theme";

const FootergEl = styled.div`
position: relative;
height: 482px;
width: 100vw;
margin-top: 196px;
background-color: ${()=>Colors.Brand.BGFooter};`;
;
```

Comment: it still displays an error msg ......  Line 10:20:  Parsing error: Missing semicolon. (10:20)

Comment: No need to use `` for props:
try:
`background-color: ${()=>Colors.Brand.BGFooter};`

Comment: updated code in my answer,after callback you will need to add ;and also need to remove ` before $